# Embeded image CID issue in SimpleJavaMail

Tags: email, java-8, mime-types

I write a Java 8 code that sends e-mails using ***SimpleJavaMail*** ( https://www.simplejavamail.org ) and I am using an HTML content that has embedded images e.g. `<img src="cid:ji">`

I add the image via `currentEmailBuilder.withEmbeddedImage("ji" , new FileDataSource("smiley.png"))`

After that, the e-mail is delivered but the image is not inline, instead comes as an attachment.

This is because `FileDataSource` does not understand the Mime Type of the png file (although it is a proper png file) and reports it by default as `application/octet-stream`.

Furthermore when the attached image  is e.g. JPG , then the mime type is properly detected but it is attached with an unexpected CID. Instead of the one that I use in the template (e.g. `ji`) it comes with the file extension along (!!) i.e. `ji.jpg` and thus the CID does not match the template so the image again does not appear properly.

**I must be doing something really wrong!**

I employed a workaround by creating a class of my own named `ExtendedFileDataSource`  that reports correct MimeType and CID but it is still very strange that I have searched a lot and nobody seems to have this or a similar problem with ***SimpleJavaMail***.

Can you help me out so that I can get rid of the extra class?

*Thank you in advance for your time!!*

Panagiotis

---

In case you need to see the code that embeds the images is:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : images.entrySet()) {
    // I use a TreeMap that maps the file path to the CID (name)
    final String path = entry.getKey();
    final String name = entry.getValue();

    // this call created the file from a custom service that I created to handle the filesyste
    final File file = FilesService.api.fileFromDbNPath(account.getDatabase(), path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCodes.MailInexistentImage, "database", account.getDatabase(), "path", path);
    }
    mailBuilder.withEmbeddedImage(name, new FileDataSource(file));
}
```

and the resulting e-mail has these two parts (among others):

```
------=_Part_2_1209984735.1634128409176
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p><b>Na =CF=84=CE=BF=CF=82 =CE=BF =CE=B1=CF=81=CF=87=CE=B7=CE=B3=CF=8C=CF=
=82:</b> =CE=9B=CE=BF=CF=8D=CE=BB=CE=B7=CF=82 =CE=A0=CE=B9=CE=BB=CE=BF=CF=
=8D=CE=BB=CE=B7=CF=82 =CE=BC=CE=B5 =CF=84o =CE=BC=CE=AD=CE=B9=CE=BB!</p><p>=
=CE=96=CE=97=CE=A4=CE=A9!!</p>
<hr>
<p><img src=3D"cid:efydpepxon"><br><img src=3D"cid:ji"><br><img src=3D"cid:=
testimage"></p>
<hr>
<h1>Fin</h1>
------=_Part_2_1209984735.1634128409176--
```

```
------=_Part_1_380493606.1634128409176
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; filename=testimage.png; name=testimage.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=testimage.png
Content-ID: <testimage.png>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQAAAAEACAMAAABrrFhUAAAC/VBMVEUXFBAiHRYrJRxOMQMzLihV
OQIOhRhEOi1eQ...............................7IwbTAwASAIPHaQDihBgQ4fUhBRQdCOx
HPaGyXeFOSEfP0LX3UwUgE+ZfgmslckQ8LdK3ik6zMM/0KX1yGoJ++AlMbAfc4Oe7wEA2lSmadFe
khgCOHdJbIL/UGaT97paY2E/5gb/H72WgFosmUw1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
------=_Part_1_380493606.1634128409176
Content-Type: image/jpeg; filename=ji.jpg; name=ji.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=ji.jpg
Content-ID: <ji.jpg>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAUEBAQEAwUEBAQGBQUGCA0ICAcHCBALDAkNExAUExIQ
EhIUFx0ZFBYcFhISGiMaHB4fISEhFBkkJyQgJh0gISD/2wBDAQUGBggHCA8ICA8gFRIVICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgI...........................NFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjN
FFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFADGVmORIy+w
x/UUUUUAf//Z
------=_Part_1_380493606.1634128409176
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mail source code show you the id `Content-ID: <testimage.png>` & `Content-ID: <ji.jpg>`. That means the id in your html file/code img has to be the same --> `<img src"cid:testimage.png"/>` & `<img src"cid:ji.jpg"/>`.

I had exactly the same issue, and never find an answer until I do it myself, so I hope my answer will help someone.

Comment: You are correct, the names has to match, but all that data are created (the wrong way) by the SimpleJavaMail java library. So what I actually ask is what is the correct way to do it (so that the resulting data is as you say) using the SimpleJavaMail  library!